# how to change size and position of searchController?.searchBar?

Tags: swift, swift2, resize, xcode7.3

I try to change size and position of searchController.searchBar for exemple 
i cahnge y from 0 to 100 but i can see any change in my programme .

here is my code :

```
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()
    resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

    searchController?.searchBar.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 600, height: 44.0 ))


         self.definesPresentationContext = true

    searchController?.searchBar.frame = (CGRectMake(0, 100,600, 44.0))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: (searchController?.searchBar)!)

    // Keep the navigation bar visible.
    searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0URX8.png)

can any body help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to change the size of a search bar or text field as another example by using the Size Inspector within that item. Also, when you set constraints for the object you can set height or width to anything you wish...within limits of the screen. Therefore, a text field with a set height of 30 can now be set to 50 or whatever you desire to fit your aesthetic. I found this by once searching for myself and finally came across it in a Udemy course for iOS 9 with Mark Price. I would forward the link but it was a paid course. Good luck!